# Stuck on apple logo

Tags: iphone

I guess I updated a new  tweak and so now when I turn my phone of then back on it stays stuck on Apple logo. So I did the whole power button home, then when it comes on I hold the up button so when Cydia goes on safe mode I have to turn phone off to get my tweaks back the problem is that when I do that it gets stuck again on the apple logo. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Factory reset, restore, re-jailbreak, don't download the offending tweak

Comment: How do I do a factory reset without updating my phone

Comment: Plug it into iTunes, select the device, click restore

Comment: Hey mitchell i went to restore my iPhone but as soon as I was going to do it it said that if I do it will be updated to the new update which means no more jail brake for me. What can I do ?

Comment: This is most likely going to be the only solution. Apps and tweaks from Cydia are offered "as is" and so if they go wrong there's not much you can do. If you know what tweak it is, you may be able to find a program on your computer to access the phones file system, and delete the tweak from there

Comment: Ok well thank Mitchell since your the only one giving me feed back on my problem. But I'm going to see which sources  are the one that Cydia first give you when you first jail take the device that way I just can uninstall the one that I have and start from the beginning. What do you think about that?